# Determinant question. I don't understand the solution

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I don't understand the solution of this problem.

Problem: Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix, $\lambda_1$ an eigenvalue of $A$, and let $I_n$ denote the identity matrix of
size $n \times n$. Recall that the multiplicity of $λ_1$ is the largest integer $k$ such that $(\lambda − \lambda_1)^k$
is a factor of
the characteristic polynomial $|\lambda I_n − A|$.
If $A$ and $B$ are two similar square matrices, show that they have the same characteristic
polynomial.

Solution: If $A = S^{-1}BS$ for some invertible matrix $S$, then

\begin{align*}
p_A(λ) &= \det(\lambda I_n - A) \\
&= \det(\lambda I_n - S^{-1}BS) \\
&= \det(S^{-1} (λI_n - B)S) \\
&= \det(S^{-1}) \det(λI_n - B) \det(S) \\
&= \det(S)^{-1} \det(λI_n - B) \det(S) \\
&= \det(λI_n - B) \\
&= p_B(λ).
\end{align*}

I don't understand this part. How can we write $S^{-1}$ in determinant like this?

$$\det(λI_n - S^{-1}BS)= \det(S^{-1}(λI_n - B)S)$$

Comment: Note that $\lambda I_n = \lambda S^{-1}I_n S = S^{-1}\lambda I_n S$.  Now, factor.  Recall that $XY+XZ=X(Y+Z)$ in order to factor an $S^{-1}$ from the left of each.  Similarly you can factor an $S$ from the right of each.

Comment: $\lambda I-S^{-1}BS=\lambda S^{-1}S-S^{-1}BS=(\lambda S^{-1}-S^{-1}B)S=
S^{-1}(\lambda I-B)S$

Comment: Thank you, I understand it right now.